# UNITY Looking for a way to store temporary global delta value for a specific spell

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unity3d-mirror

I am kind of new to unity and currently designing a spell architecture in a **multi-player game** that could make spell parameters vary with the environment(e.g. character, equipment, buffs, etc...).

Yes, it is a **multi-player game** and I am using `Mirror` as the multi-player service framework, which means I may consider these `delta values` as sync vars.

For example, I designed a fireball spell. The damage of this spell may increase because I could gain a buff. My idea is to use a `scriptable object` to store the basic parameter values of the spell(e.g. damage, spell radius, etc...), and then all delta values(e.g. damage increment) would be collected somewhere. This place should be exclusive to a player.

In this way, I can calculate the total damage by just adding all delta values on the basic damage stored in the scriptable object.

**My question is where to store these delta values for every spell separately?**

Is there a global way to store these delta values without instantiating an object?

I tried `scriptable objects` but as they are assets, maybe it is not a good idea to use them in this non-persistent scenario. I wish these delta values could be collected by GC when I do not need them.

I also tried to create `scriptable objects` at runtime but it doesn't work as well. I don't want to access these `scriptable objects` after instantiating the object, and `scriptable objects` no longer exist when the object is destroyed. I want these delta values could be in a global variable that accompanies the entire life cycle of the game. So I can keep firing fireballs that improve damage.

The character(hero) already have a temporary scriptable object to store delta values for all spell. But what if I only want to improve specific spell damage like fireball?

Or there actually is a better architecture to implement this spell system without storing delta values separately?

After @derHugo reminder(very much appreciate it), I found that I forgot to explain that this is a multiplayer game. A simple static class for all players may not solve this problem.

Comment: `I want these delta values could be in a global variable that accompanies the entire life cycle of the game` -> Why not simply use a `public static class`? Or in general a `static` multiplier? Or let it be e.g. a `static` list of multipliers you can add and remove according to your needs ...

Comment: Ok since it is a multi-player game, a global static class would have impacts on all plays' spells. I want each player to have a separate place to store their own delta values. Very much appreciate @derHugo pointed out what I missed in the question. It is a multi-player game.

Comment: Doesn't change anything tbh .. then have a static dictionary and store each players multipliers individually .. though tbh actually you would only need the stats of your own player anyway .. the stats of other players would come synced via the network .. so there is no need to store these on your side anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can meet my need without storing delta spell parameters. They can be calculated dynamically by other `SpellCalculator`.

If I insist, I can also store the delta spell parameters by dynamically creating `ScriptableObject` at run time. Obviously, this is unnecessary.